# pgpoolamin V3.5.2 parameter-check .pcpass Invalide permision

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

[image]

The path is ok, and the .pcppass file has www-data rights.

Does anybody an idea who to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

according to the php sourcecode the `/var/www/.pcppass` need **permission** to `600` or `rw- --- ---`